# How do I set a border-image?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code in which a QR-code is generated via AJAX :

```
<div class="qr-border">
    <p id="qr" class="ajax_qrcode{if $cart_qties < 1} hidden{/if}"></p>
</div>
```

and I would like to set a border image around the QR-code. I have this image :

[image: small image to repeat]

and a right corner image :

[image: corner image]

So I tried this in the CSS :

```
div.qr-border p.ajax_qrcode {

    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 1.0em;
    float: center;
    border-image: url('../img/qr-code-border/border.png') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch;
    border-bottom-right-image: url('../img/qr-code-border/corner.png');
}
```

but nothing works... Do someone has any suggestion ?

thank you for your help !

Comment: What browser are you using? Not all browsers support `border-image`.

Comment: I'm using firefox 4.0.1 and the latest chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible at the moment in any browser. I don't know of any browser that has implemented the full set of rules. Webkit, for example only seems to have implemented the shorthand `border-image` property. So you will not be able to set a separate *right* image.

[This site](http://css-tricks.com/6883-understanding-border-image/) has the best explanation of how CSS3 border-image works. It also has an [interactive demo](http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/border-image-anim.html) from which I take the following quote:

> The border-image property in CSS3 is freakin' complicated. Way beyond a simple border, it is really like 9-slice scaling.

I don't actually think it's even possible to do what you want with CSS3 border-image even if a browser *had* implemented the full set due to the way in which a single image is sliced up to make a border.

Comment: I opted for another div container with a border image that fit the QR-code, as you quoted, this is way too complicated for what I wanted to do. =)

Answer (score 1):

border-image is a very new property in CSS3, and as far as i know, no browser supports it natively.

However, you can probably get it to work in Chrome and Safari by using the proprietary -webkit-border-image property instead.

Edit: try -moz-border-image for firefox as well.

Edit again: Your css selector is wrong, there's your problem. It should look like this:

```
div.qr-border p.ajax_qrcode
```

You treated the qr-border class as an ID.

Comment: I tried `code`-moz-border-image: url('../img/qr-code-border/border.png') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch; and `code`-webkit-border-image: url('../img/qr-code-border/border.png') 27 27 27 27 stretch stretch; But it doesn't change anything

Comment: Ow indeed I did many changes and forgot to change the CSS selector, but even with the ight selector, nothing changes on Firefox/Chrome, maybe it would be easier to generate the border via php rather than CSS ?

Comment: Well, i tried it out, and with the latest chrome, -webkit should work just dandy. Should the fit values all be 27? Play around with some other values.

Comment: The border image iz displayed, but I don't understand how to set values so that it encloses the QR-code

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a straight black border, why not just place the image in a slightly larger box (div) and make the background color black? The margin between the outside of the box and the QR-image should be black, and should ultimately provide the same effect right? Unless QR codes work differently with transparency...

Comment: Indeed QR-Codes are not legible when placed into a black background. I don't understand why, since position and alignment patterns are visible