# Can you assign an image to border-right?

Tags: html, css, image, border

I am making a navigational menu in html and css, but i want the border right of each navigational item to be an image.

I tried

```
border-right:url(image.jpg);
```

But this didn't work.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a background image and then position the background image to the right of each element.  Usually this would go on either the `a` tag or `li`. For example:

```
#primaryNav a:link { 
 background-image: url('image.jpg');
 background-position: right;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: block; /* make the link background clickable */
}
```

If you don't want the border applied to the last (when using `background-position: right;`) or first (for `background-position: left;`) element in your menu then try the `:last-child` and `:first-child` selectors.

```
#primaryNav a:last-child {
   background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can set custom border size. Top, left and bottom will be 0px and set a border-image. If you want to decorate these borders with other style then use sub div.

Right image decoreted div style is:

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
-moz-border-image: url(border.png) 27 repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(border.png) 27 repeat;
-o-border-image: url(border.png) 27 repeat;
border-image: url(border.png) 27 fill repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a new feature of CSS 3 and the property is called [border-image](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images). Unfortunately, it's [not yet widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image) by today's browsers as it's still a candidate recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

`#primaryNav a:link { 
 background: url('image.jpg') no-repeat right;

 display: block;
 }`

Typically good practice to code your background property's on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

There's a css property called `border-image` which could be what you're after. I'm not sure what the current browser support for it is though...

Answer (score 0):

It is not actually recommended to do it this way. See this thread for details: [How do I set a border-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385563/how-do-i-set-a-border-image)