# can we set different border-image for every side of div?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a div with a picture frame design by using border-image property. 
[frame.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR2X0.jpg)
It is left side frame image.
Can any one suggest me how can i apply it to right side?

I am not interested using javascript to handle it..
CSS3 solution please...

Comment: Might already be answered. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948447/can-you-assign-an-image-to-border-right)

Comment: Sorry. But That wasnt my solution

Comment: If you already have it working for the left side, why note show us your code?

Comment: its not working yet. I just uploaded a demo image of a left frame.

Answer (score 1):

While you might think the browser would assume "take this image and tile it all the way around" you'd be wrong. Border-image is way more versatile than that and provides all kinds of ways to slice and dice the same image to get very different results. The assumptions the CSS3 border-image property makes about the image you provide are not intuitive! Start by reading this article to get an excellent explanation of each individual property of border-image: [CSS-Tricks: border-image](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/).

```css
.mydiv {
  padding: 20px 38px;
  border-image-source: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR2X0.jpg);
  border-image-width: auto;
  border-image-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <h1>
    Headline: Breaking News!
  </h1>
</div>
```

Until you have a feel for the property, I'd suggest setting each part individually (instead of using the omnibus shorthand property - like setting border-width, border style, and border-color instead of just using border). 
You can also experiment with [this border-image generator](http://border-image.com/)  which is a great way to develop the feel of how the browser will slice and dice your image.

Comment: You are very close to answer.. But see the right side. It still look like left side.. any Solution on it ?

Comment: Did you check out the border generator link? It shows how your image gets sliced. In order for it to be sliced the way you want (presumably so that the image gets flipped for the other side) you'll have to provide an image that flips. (So have your left-side and your right-side side-by-side in the same image. You can't tell it use this one and use that one - you only get one setting for image source.)